# Change "from [name]"/"offered by [name]" in a Chrome extension's Webstore listing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have created a Chrome extension.
By default it took my Gmail id in the "from xyzpqr".

[image: CWS listing]

How can I change my Gmail id to something different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the displayed name (per publisher account, not per item) at your [Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard/):

[image: Developer Dashboard options]

Exceptions to the rule:

1. If your Webstore item is [associated with a verified website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920728/how-to-specify-verified-site-to-a-chrome-app), say `http://example.com/`, it will display "offered by [example.com](http://example.com/)" with no possibility to change it except for removing the association.
2. You can be part of, and create, [Group Publishing accounts](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#set-up-group-publishing). Items transferred to Group Publishing accounts have an independent display name.
   **Make sure you read [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#set-up-group-publishing) thoroughly before you use this feature, as it is in many ways irreversible!** (for example, you can't transfer items back, and you can ever create only one such account)

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you; to get a tracker ID for the web store listing, just go to http://www.google.com/analytics/ and register a new property.

Comment: @Xan how can I associate my webstore item with a verified website. Thanks?

Comment: @PyQL See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920728/how-to-specify-verified-site-to-a-chrome-app - I'll add that to the answer.