# How to specify verified site to a chrome app?

Tags: installation, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to enable [inline installs](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation), but continue to get the following error

```
Inline installs can only be initiated for Chrome Web Store items that have one or more verified sites
```

I've verified ownership of my test site via both a name tag and a .html file.  Is it a problem that this test site is also owned by my other email (for analytics)?  This is all being tested in Canary, where I'm signed in with a work email.

In the Developer Dashboard, I've changed my display name to be the site I verified (e.g. www.example.com).  I've also enabled the checkbox for `This item uses inline install.`

It's not clear how I associate the site I own with the app I publish on the chrome web store.

It seems like I'd need to specify the site I own in the manifest file?

In my www.mydomain.com/testfile.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>blu</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/favicon.png">

    <link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/myAppIdNumber">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 600px; margin: 40px auto;">
      <h1>
        Example Install Page
      </h1>

      <p>
        You can initiate app and extension installations "inline" from your site. These apps and extensions are still hosted in the <a href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps">Chrome Web Store</a>, but users no longer have to leave your site to install them.
      </p>

      <button onclick="chrome.webstore.install(undefined, undefined, function(message) { console.log(message); });" id="install-button">
        Add to Chrome
      </button>

      <script>
        if (chrome.app.isInstalled) {
          document.getElementById('install-button').style.display = 'none';
        }
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say "verified ownership of my test site", did you do that in the way described on this page: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not about your display name.

You need to:

1. Go to the [Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/).
2. [Add the site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en) to your sites.
3. Obtain and embed a verification code into your site.
4. Complete verification in Webmaster Tools.
5. Go to your [Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) (must be under the same Google account) and edit your Web Store item.
6. Select your site in *"Verify that this is an official item for a website you own:"*

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that I had to add a site by editing the app deployment configs through the Developer Dashboard.

Comment: I think this list is incomplete. I feel like I do step 1 through 5 and there is still an empty list in step 6.

Comment: @Redsandro Are you certain you completed verification? Visit Webmaster tools again.