# Testing Chrome Extension APIs Locally

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, testing, google-chrome-extension, oauth

This is a pretty general question with a couple examples.  I'm fairly new to writing chrome extensions and I seem to keep running into cases that are impossible to test without deploying to the webstore (which takes ~60m each time). This is an impossible workflow. Am I missing something?

**Case 1 inline installation**

Trying to set up inline installation from my site to a chrome extension.  When I run the site locally i get the following.

`Error downloading extension: Inline installs can only be initiated for Chrome Web Store items that have one or more verified sites.`

But I cannot seem to add localhost website property in chrome's developer dashboard.  What is the recommended way to do this in a dev environment.  I tried using local.mywebsite.com and adding a local alias for localhost, but now chrome cannot find the verification file you are required to serve...

**Case 2 Chrome Extension OAuth**

Attempting to use `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` to setup user credentials in my extension for my website, but of course the callback url provided `https://<ext-id>.chromium.org/provider-cb` does not redirect to my local deploy of the extension.

Is there no way to test these things??

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your error *"Inline installs can only be initiated for Chrome Web Store items that have one or more verified sites."*, you may follow the instructions given in this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25922123/5832311).

You need to:

1. Go to the [Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/).
2. [Add the site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en) to your sites.
3. Obtain and embed a verification code into your site.
4. Complete verification in Webmaster Tools.
5. Go to your [Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) (must be under the same Google account) and edit your Web Store item.
6. Select your site in *"Verify that this is an official item for a website you own:"*

Here are some references which might help in testing extensions:

- [Testing browser extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798528/testing-browser-extensions/17370531#17370531)
- [How to test chrome extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869827/how-to-test-chrome-extensions)